# Linking errors with MinGW32 and Assimp

Tags: c++, mingw, assimp

I'm trying to build Assimp using MinGW32, but it is giving the following errors:

> [ 69%] Linking CXX executable assimp.exe
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x42):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*,
>   Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xac):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::ValidateFlags(unsigned int)
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xee):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*,
>   unsigned int)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x182):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*,
>   Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x1c1):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x1f7):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::GetErrorString() const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x2c0):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::Export(aiScene const*, char
>   const*, char const*, unsigned int, Assimp::ExportProperties const*)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x353):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Exporter::GetErrorString() const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x42a):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*,
>   Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x43c):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xeff):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*,
>   unsigned int)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x51):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x7):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::~Exporter()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x12):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc7):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe1):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::SetPropertyInteger(char
>   const*, int)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf9):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::Exporter()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1af):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::IsExtensionSupported(char
>   const*) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1de):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::~Exporter()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e9):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x237):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetCompileFlags'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x23e):
>   undefined reference to`aiGetVersionRevision'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b4):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMinor'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2bb):
>   undefined reference to`aiGetVersionMajor'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x36a):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x382):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x41d):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x43a):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4c9):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::GetExtensionList(aiString&)
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x56c):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*,
>   unsigned int)'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x3ae3):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetVersionRevision'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x3b0d):
>   undefined reference to`aiGetCompileFlags'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x4373):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetVersionRevision'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x437a):
>   undefined reference to`aiGetVersionMinor'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x4381):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMajor'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x1db7):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Importer::GetMemoryRequirements(aiMemoryInfo&) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x2245):
>   undefined reference to `aiGetMaterialString'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x238e):
>   undefined reference to`aiGetMaterialString'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x15):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x41):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x79):
>   undefined reference to
>   `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x66c):
>   undefined reference to`Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x695):
>   undefined reference to
>   `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x6cc):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x955):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x985):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0xe97):
>   undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount()
>   const'
>       c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0xec5):
>   undefined reference to`
>   Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned int) const'
>       collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       tools\assimp_cmd\CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir\build.make:192: recipe for target 'tools/assimp_cmd/assimp.exe' failed
>       make[2]: *** [tools/assimp_cmd/assimp.exe] Error 1
>       CMakeFiles\Makefile2:293: recipe for target 'tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/all' failed
>       make[1]: *** [tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeFiles/assimp_cmd.dir/all] Error 2
>       Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
>       make: *** [all] Error 2

I am not able to understand how to resolve these errors

Comment: I downloaded the source code from here: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v5.0.1

Then I used Cmake to generate the Makefile for Assimp, and then I used mingw32-make to build it. At 69%, it gave these errors

Comment: the same issue. Assimp constantly has such problems